# How to add data filter to my google sheets header

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I want to add a filter to the header in my google sheet. I found [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111483/looking-for-examples-how-to-use-the-google-sheets-api-filtercriteria-object) using C# and tried to build the JSON from it. This is what I come up with but no luck :

```
{'AddFilterViewRequest' : {
      'AddFilterViewResponse': {
      'Filter' : {
                  'FilterView': {
                  'title' : "Hide rows with errors",
                  'range': {'sheetId': sheet_id,
                            'startRowIndex': 0,
                            'endRowIndex': 2,
                            'startColumnIndex': 1,
                            'endColumnIndex': 31}
                  }
      }
      }
}}
```

Anyone knows what I'm going wrong?

Comment: This might be asking a lot but could you add some code that allows us to [see/verify](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) how you are using this JSON object?

Comment: I want to add a simple filter on my excel header for user to able to filter through the possible values. the above code is the only thing I have, sorry.

Comment: Maybe Im off the mark as it may be obvious to someone with extensive knowledge of google sheets api but can you show some of your python code, how it interacts with sheets, whats supposed to happen and what is actually haooeneing? This would let me more easily understand what may be going wrong

Answer (score 4):

From the [Google Sheets API documentation](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/sheets/v4/python/latest/sheets_v4.spreadsheets.html):

> ```
> "addFilterView": { # Adds a filter view. # Adds a filter view.
>       "filter": { # A filter view. # The filter to add. The filterViewId
>           # field is optional; if one is not set, an id will be randomly generated. (It
>           # is an error to specify the ID of a filter that already exists.)
>         "title": "A String", # The name of the filter view.
>         "namedRangeId": "A String", # The named range this filter view is backed by, if any.
>             #
>             # When writing, only one of range or named_range_id
>             # may be set.
>         "filterViewId": 42, # The ID of the filter view.
>         "range": { # A range on a sheet. # The range this filter view covers.
>             #
>             # When writing, only one of range or named_range_id
>             # may be set.
>             # All indexes are zero-based.
>             # Indexes are half open, e.g the start index is inclusive
>             # and the end index is exclusive -- [start_index, end_index).
>             # Missing indexes indicate the range is unbounded on that side.
>             #
>             # For example, if `"Sheet1"` is sheet ID 0, then:
>             #
>             #   `Sheet1!A1:A1 == sheet_id: 0,
>             #                   start_row_index: 0, end_row_index: 1,
>             #                   start_column_index: 0, end_column_index: 1`
>             #
>             #   `Sheet1!A3:B4 == sheet_id: 0,
>             #                   start_row_index: 2, end_row_index: 4,
>             #                   start_column_index: 0, end_column_index: 2`
>             #
>             #   `Sheet1!A:B == sheet_id: 0,
>             #                 start_column_index: 0, end_column_index: 2`
>             #
>             #   `Sheet1!A5:B == sheet_id: 0,
>             #                  start_row_index: 4,
>             #                  start_column_index: 0, end_column_index: 2`
>             #
>             #   `Sheet1 == sheet_id:0`
>             #
>             # The start index must always be less than or equal to the end index.
>             # If the start index equals the end index, then the range is empty.
>             # Empty ranges are typically not meaningful and are usually rendered in the
>             # UI as `#REF!`.
>           "endRowIndex": 42, # The end row (exclusive) of the range, or not set if unbounded.
>           "endColumnIndex": 42, # The end column (exclusive) of the range, or not set if unbounded.
>           "sheetId": 42, # The sheet this range is on.
>           "startColumnIndex": 42, # The start column (inclusive) of the range, or not set if unbounded.
>           "startRowIndex": 42, # The start row (inclusive) of the range, or not set if unbounded.
>         },
>         "sortSpecs": [ # The sort order per column. Later specifications are used when values
>             # are equal in the earlier specifications.
>           { # A sort order associated with a specific column or row.
>             "sortOrder": "A String", # The order data should be sorted.
>             "dimensionIndex": 42, # The dimension the sort should be applied to.
>           },
>         ],
>         "criteria": { # The criteria for showing/hiding values per column.
>             # The map's key is the column index, and the value is the criteria for
>             # that column.
>           "a_key": { # Criteria for showing/hiding rows in a filter or filter view.
>             "hiddenValues": [ # Values that should be hidden.
>               "A String",
>             ],
>             "condition": { # A condition that can evaluate to true or false. # A condition that must be true for values to be shown.
>                 # (This does not override hiddenValues -- if a value is listed there,
>                 #  it will still be hidden.)
>                 # BooleanConditions are used by conditional formatting,
>                 # data validation, and the criteria in filters.
>               "values": [ # The values of the condition. The number of supported values depends
>                   # on the condition type.  Some support zero values,
>                   # others one or two values,
>                   # and ConditionType.ONE_OF_LIST supports an arbitrary number of values.
>                 { # The value of the condition.
>                   "relativeDate": "A String", # A relative date (based on the current date).
>                       # Valid only if the type is
>                       # DATE_BEFORE,
>                       # DATE_AFTER,
>                       # DATE_ON_OR_BEFORE or
>                       # DATE_ON_OR_AFTER.
>                       #
>                       # Relative dates are not supported in data validation.
>                       # They are supported only in conditional formatting and
>                       # conditional filters.
>                   "userEnteredValue": "A String", # A value the condition is based on.
>                       # The value will be parsed as if the user typed into a cell.
>                       # Formulas are supported (and must begin with an `=`).
>                 },
>               ],
>               "type": "A String", # The type of condition.
>             },
>           },
>         },
>       },
>     }
> ```

I haven't tried using a filter myself but it seems like the keys `AddFilterViewRequest`, `AddFilterViewRequest` and `Filter` aren't required.

Comment: Can someone show an example of the condition part being filled in with sample data? I am not sure on all of what I do not know but I think the first step is to figure out where to put the column number index.

Comment: Thank you Ray for the example. Do you know how to apply that Filter view to the sheet? because now it does only create a view that you could see under Filter View from Data dropdown list.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my approach with gspread while researching on how to do this.

```
# authenticate to googlesheets
from google.colab import auth
from google.auth import default
auth.authenticate_user()
creds, _ = default()

# import gspread to interact with gsheets and authenticate gspread to google
import gspread
gc = gspread.authorize(creds)

#get spreadsheet
ss = gc.open_by_key('<longassspreadsheetsheetid>')
#get worksheet id (aka : SheetId as per google)
ws_id = ss.worksheet('<wsname>').id
# set the action on sheet to be requested
requests = [
  {
    "setBasicFilter": 
    {
      "filter":
      {
        "range": 
        {    
          "sheetId": ,
          "startColumnIndex": 0, #column A
          "endColumnIndex": 4 #column D
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
#prepare the body object with the request to send it to google
body = {
  'requests': requests
}
#send the update
ss.batch_update(body)
```

sources:

- [Automate Google Sheets Autofilter with Sheets API in Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GyRxsSlx0GU)
- [Set Basic Filter Request](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/filters)