# How to use 'find' in Google Sheets API (Cocos Creator)

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api, cocoscreator

I am using Cocos Creator to build a web app that will communicate with google sheets.
I didn't manage to find a suitable client library (as highlighted in below link)
 https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/integrating-google-sheets-api/47920

And decided to go with the REST api using http requests.

However, I am unable to find documents that show exactly how to perform the requests i need.

**UPDATE:**
Updated the title as I realized my previous approach of condition check is meant for filter views, which i misunderstood it's use case.

However, i saw this video showing that you can use the 'find' function that will return the cell grid, which is exactly what i'm looking for.
https://youtu.be/yPQ2Gk33b1U?t=348

I would like to know how to construct the request string to perform this call on the REST api using http request.

*Previously:*
<strike>As the title says, I need a condition check to for searching my sheet and return the cell that has the exact match for a given string.
This link documents that such conditions exist but does not show how to execute it with http request
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/other</strike>

I've found this post that is performing something very similar to what I wish to request, using FilterCriteria and Condition.

[Looking for examples how to use the Google Sheets API FilterCriteria object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38111483/looking-for-examples-how-to-use-the-google-sheets-api-filtercriteria-object)

However, he is using the C# client library but is there any that I can use for Cocos Creator? As such, I have to perform this with REST using Http Request, and I have no leads on how to construct the request string.

```
var http = require('http');

var obj = {
    'key' : 'MY_API_KEY'
}

var filters = {
    'dataFilters': [
        {
            'Condition' : {
                'type' : 'TEXT_EQ',
                'values' : [{ 'userEnteredValue' : 'string_to_match' }]
            },
        }
    ]
}
var filtersStr = JSON.stringify(filters);

http.Get('MY_GOOGLE_SHEET_ID:getByDataFilter' + filtersStr, obj, function(responseJson)
{
     console.log(responseJson);
});
```

Above code is something i attempted, but you bet it is not working.

Comment: Can you provide the detail information about `not working`?

Comment: @Tanaike it's not working because it returns an error. When i check back at the link on how the person used the FilterCriteria and Condition, i realise i am have misunderstood its use case.
Hence i have updated my question now.